# Implementing transaction fee for auction sites using Google Checkout

Tags: e-commerce, google-checkout

Suppose there is an auction site that uses google checkout exclusively. How would one set things up so that when the buyer sends money to the seller google checkout sends something like 1% of it to the auction site much like how ebay charges a fee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Checkout is a payment flow between one seller and one buyer. There is no support for automatic third party commissions.

You need to setup two separate transactions where the seller pays the auction broker the commission or listing fee.